# Inherited member new property

Tags: c#

I have a class `Item`:

```
   public class Item
    {
        public int ID { get; private set; }
        public int Value { get; private set; }

        public Item CachedReference
        {
            get
            {
                return Server.Instance.Data.Items[this.ID];
            }
        }

        public Item(int id)
        {
            this.ID = id;
            this.Value = this.CachedReference.Value;
        }
}
```

I have a class `Equip` that derives from `Item`:

```
public sealed class Equip : Item
{
    public new Equip CachedReference
    {
        get
        {
            return Server.Instance.Data.Equips[this.ID];
        }
    }
}

public Equip(int id) : base(id) { }
```

When I'm calling:

```
Equip equip = new Equip(id);
```

The constructor of `Item` base will use the `CachedReference` property of `Item`, and not the new `CachedReference` property of `Equip`. How can I make it so if I initialize an object of type `Equip`, the base `Item` class will use the `CachedReference` value of `Equip` and not of `Item`?

Comment: By creating a new constructor in `Equip` that calls a new, parameterless base constructor which does nothing, or by using `virtual` and `override` instead of `new`. What have you tried?

Comment: @CodeCaster The problem is that because `Equip` derives from `Item`, it also needs the `Value` property. Therefore I do want the base class to get the basic values.

Comment: @CodeCaster I did use the virtual method and overriden it with `Equip`, but I want `CachedReference` to return `Equip` type and not `Item` so I wouldn't have to cast it in my constructor.

Comment: Could generics be an option here?

Answer (score 0):

*Usually*, the ideal way to do that *automatically* is for `CachedReference` to be a `virtual` method (or: indirectly *invoke* a `virtual` method), that `Equip` *overrides*.

However! In this case, you're talking about a constructor; you should **not** call a `virtual` method during a constructor. Instead, one other way is to pass the desired value *down* via the constructor (it could be a different `protected` constructor for this purpose).

For example:

```
private static GetCachedReference(int id)
   => Server.Instance.Data.Items[id];
public Item(int id) : (id, GetCachedReference(id).Value) {}
protected Item(int id, int value)
{
    this.ID = id;
    this.Value = value;
}
```

---

```
private static GetCachedReference(int id)
   => Server.Instance.Data.Equips[this.ID];
public Item CachedReference => GetCachedReference(ID);
public new Equip CachedReference => GetCachedReference(ID);
public Equip(int id) : base(id, GetCachedReference(id).Value) { }
```

Comment: Can you show me an example? I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams an example added, but there's about 6 different ways of laying this out, including storing the reference itself, not the value, and doing the .Value in the getter

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking I'd say that this is a bad design. Your class (Item) is handling 2 things at once (storing value and caching). Let's say for example later you want to change the cache mechanism (to Redis or sth), it would be very difficult.

Bottom line is you should have a separate class/interface to handle caching.

This is a (very) simplified version

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public Item(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}

public class Equip : Item
{
    public Equip(int id) : base(id)
    {
    }
}

public class CacheManager
{
    public TItem GetItem<TItem>(int id) where TItem : Item
    {
        if (typeof(TItem) == typeof(Equip))
        {
            return Server.Instance.Data.Equips[id];
        }

        return Server.Instance.Data.Items[id];
    }
}
```